# Logic Apps subscribe to a topic within an event grid domain

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-eventgrid

My question is in related Azure logic apps / Event Grid.

I have set up an **Event Grid Domain** with multiple topics. I would like the create a logic app that will subscribe to topics within my Event **Grid Domain**. The flow trigger for the event grid domain appears to be missing the Topic field to allow it only to subscribe to particular topics. am I missing something?

How can I have a logic app subscribe specifically to one topic within an event grid domain in Azure?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this is a limitation with the UI. If you were to use custom values for both the `Resource Type` and `Resource Name` like below, I can confirm it works as expected

[image: eventgrid-trigger-with-custom-values]

Also, feel free to raise a [feature request on UserVoice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps) to support this in the UI.